# ActionPerformed SignUp Query database - JAVA GUI

Tags: java, database, user-interface

i just wanna ask you about what's wrong about my code..
Here's my code..

```
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if(e.getSource()==btnsubmit){
        String Id= String.format("U%03d", countData);
        String query="INSERT INTO MsUser(UserID, Username, UserPass, UserFullName, UserEmail, UserPhone, UserAddress, UserGender, Role) VALUES('"+Id+"','"+txtuser.getText()+"','"+txtpass.getText()+"','"+txtname.getText()+"','"+txtemail.getText()+"','"+txtphone.getText()+"','"+txtadd.getText()+"')";
        con.executeUpdate(query);
        countData=1;
    }else{
        System.exit(0);
    }
```

and I want if i press submit button, the registration form input to my database.. What should I do? I already had Connect class too.. 
Here's my connect class code..

```
        public ResultSet executeQuery(String query) {
            try {
                rs = st.executeQuery(query);
                rsm = rs.getMetaData();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
                System.out.println("Error Connection RS");
            }
            return rs;
        }

        public void executeUpdate(String query){
            try {
                st.executeUpdate(query);
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

My database use .mdb, in it has UserID, Username, UserPass, UserFullName, UserEmail, UserPhone, UserAddress, UserGender, Role in MsUser Table..
Is it something missing? I'm sorry about my bad english, I wish u guys can understand what I mean..